# What is the definition of a redex and what are they for in programming languages literature?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, operational-semantics, denotational-semantics

I saw the word "redex" in the context of proramming language theory/semantics in 2018 and now when I was reading a neurosymbolic [research paper](https://pldi21.sigplan.org/details/pldi-2021-papers/55/DreamCoder-Bootstrapping-Inductive-Program-Synthesis-with-Wake-Sleep-Library-Learnin) (machine learning with neural nets + symbolic algorithms).

The research paper said:

> Constructing $I\beta'$ (operator that inverts one step of beta-reductions/function applications) depends on careful consideration of the reduction operator we aim to invert (see [39] and Appen- dix F). The operator $I\beta'$ builds both top-level redexes and also recurses to build redexes within the body of an expression

[The 2018 course](https://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/2018/cs522/CS522-Fall-2018-MSOS-RSEC-CHAM.pdf) says:

> In an RSEC language definition one starts by defining the syntax of evaluation contexts, or simply just contexts, which is typically done by means of a context-free grammar (CFG). A context is a program or a fragment of program with a hole, where the hole, which is written $\Box$ , is a placeholder for where the next computational step can take place. If $c$ is an evaluation context and $e$ is some well-formed appropriate fragment (expression, statement, etc.),
> then $c[e]$ is the program or fragment obtained by replacing the hole of $c$ by $e$. Reduction semantics with evaluation contexts relies on a tacitly assumed
> (but rather advanced) parsing mechanism that takes a program or a fragment $p$ and decomposes it into a context $c$ and a subprogram or fragment $e$, called a redex, such that $p = c[e]$. This decomposition process is called splitting (of $p$ into $c$ and $e$). The inverse process, composing a redex $e$ and a context $c$ into a program or fragment $p$, is called plugging (of $e$ into $c$). These splitting/plugging operations are depicted in Figure 3.28.

[image]

**So is a redex just a fragment of a program? Is that all? Curious why this needs a term of its own. It's use and importance.**

---

cross: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-definition-of-a-redex-and-what-are-they-for-in-programming-languages-theory

Answer (score 2):

A redex is an expressions on which we can perform a computation step, such as:

1. `fst (a, b)` is a redex, it computes to `a`
2. `snd (a, b)` is a redex, it computes to `b`
3. `(λ x . x + x) 6` is a redex, it computes to `6 + 6`
4. `if true then A else B` is a redex, it computes to `A`

Here are some examples which are *not* redexes: `fst p`, `if x < 6 then 3 else 4`, `42`, `λ x . x + x`.

An expression may *contain* a redex, for instance in

```
λ x . if x < 6 then fst (4, 5) else x
```

there is a redex, namely `fst (4, 5)`. In general, an expression may contain main redexes. Which ones are evaluated and in what order depends on how the language is designed.